Matching the values of a column in r
Suppose there is an election database. The datatable consists of candidate party name and number of votes he secured. This information is in columns for every candidate who fought the election. So the column variables in the datframe are as FIRST_PARTY FIRST_VOTE SECOND_PARTY SECOND_VOTE and so on. Here FIRST_PARTY is the party id of the first position holder in the election and FIRST_VOTE is the number of votes secured. In this dataset  I  enter INC1 INC2 INC3 as columns where party id of the incumbent government (government already in power) are given.
Now I want to find the party id of the incumbent government from the dataset (from FIRST_PARTY, SECOND_PARTY and so on) and then create a new variable 'vote' = the vote of that party id.
Eg. if FIRST_PARTY value matches with any of INC1, INC2 or INC3, I generate VOTE=FIRST_VOTE
For this I first created a list of all columns in the database (ps7 is our master datafile)
list1 <- colnames(ps7) # create a list of all variables in ps7
list2 <- list1[grep("_PRTY",list1)] # subset elements that have _PRTY in it. 
list3 <- gsub('_PRTY','',list2) # we extract the frs, sec, trd and so on 

Now a run a for loop taking each element in the list. I append the element with '_PRTY' and if it matches with any of INC1 INC2 or INC3 , I return the vote of that party (append(list3[element],'_VOTES') in a 'vote' variable . I run the following code
ps7$vote <- 0 # Create a vote variable in the dataset

for(element in list3) {  ps8 <- ps7 %>% mutate(vote=ifelse(if_any (c("inc1","inc2","inc3"),     .fns=~.==append(unlist(list3[element],'_PRTY'))), unlist(append(list3[element],'_VOTES')), vote)) }`

But in this case I do not get the correct vote value ?
If anyone may help as to how to do this?
